# responses or responds

Tags: word-choice

If we want to compare a company's employees by the number of time they responded to an email:

> Employee A: number of responses = x
>
> or
>
> Employee A: number of responds = x

Which is more accurate in this context?

Comment: "Respond" is not a noun, so you can't say "a respond" or "five responds" or "number of responds".  That said, it is common in business English to turn verbs into nouns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My choice would be **'responses'**

Here is said why: http://www.perrinator.com/response-vs-respond-the-common-mistakes-made/

> The word “respond” is a verb, and it describes the action of replying.
>   A noun is used to describe almost everything that we can see or able
>   to talk about, i.e., actions, animals, ideas / concepts, objects /
>   things, people and places. The word “response” is a noun, and  it is a
>   reply or an answer to a question or something that requires a
>   response.